# Android opening an Intent with an if statement

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a game I am making. I have it to where once the player loses all their health, they need to see the end game actvity. I have everything setup and I am not receiving any errors. But my activity never opens even if the if statement is true. I have a sample of my code below.

```
case R.id.button:                                                                      
Intent go = new Intent(this, mainactivity.class)   
if(health == 0 ){  
    Intent i = new  Intent(this, GameOver.class);  
    startActivity(i); 
}   
break;
```

I have the deduction of health being done above this, and I have toasted the value of health.
When the value hits 0 the mainactivity is opening. Basically the mainactivity is always opening. I can't figure out why it is not opening the GameOver activity. I am new to code so I may be doing this wrong or missing something, go easy on me.

Comment: Show us more about `health`. What type is it? Place an `assert()` to be sure its value is 0.

Comment: show complete source code from this class

Comment: because you open another activity afterwards. don't.

Answer (score 2):

Can it because you do `startActivity(go)` some time soon after you have done `startActivity(i)` (such as later after the `switch`). So your `mainactivity` pops up and hides your `gameover` activity beneath.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact code, you don't have a semicolon after:

```
Intent go = new Intent(this, mainactivity.class)
```

It shouldn't even run. Why do you even have it, you're obviously not using it in this scope?

Are you certain that your health cannot go below 0?

Comment: Wow I can't believe this was just a bracket if/else problem. I have it fixed now and working perfectly. Thanks for your help pointing it out to me, and sorry to waste your time on this